# TE2000 HMI Event logger - Save in text file

Tags: html, plc, twincat

Is that possible to save the events in text file or any other readable format.
If so, could you give us some pointers how to achieve it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a sqlite file `C:\ProgramData\Beckhoff\TF2000 TwinCAT 3 HMI Server\logger.db` on the target system where all the events are in. You could write a javascript function which parses the sqlite-content to a format you like.